# VUE Как при клике добавлять класс всем эл., кроме элементу на который нажали

Tags: javascript, vue.js

VUE
Доброго времени суток. Возникла проблема, как задать класс при клике всем элементам в массиве, кроме элемента на который нажали? Н данный момент получается только [так](https://jsfiddle.net/h03tfaex/4/). Но с начало они не должны быть выделены, только после клика добавляться класс

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      activeEl: false,
      items: [
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="i in items" :key="i" class="choose_number" :class="{'active': activeEl != i}" @click="activeEl = i">Элемент {{ i.content }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

.

Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как во Vue Достать элемент из списка, чтобы потом присвоить ему класс по клику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266674/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%be-vue-%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: и еще - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332579/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be-vuejs/1332868#1332868

Comment: Вероятно, проблема XY. Может быть, достаточно будет повесить класс на кликнутый элемент, а при стилизации использовать псевдокласс `:not()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так? https://jsfiddle.net/trs7ob9z/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => {
    return {
      activeEl: false,
      items: [
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        },
        {
            content: 'hhhhh'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li 
      v-for="i in items" 
      :key="i" 
      class="choose_number" 
      :class="activeEl !== i && activeEl !== false ? 'active' : ''" 
      @click="activeEl = i"
    >
      Элемент {{ i.content }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```